# $5^m = 2 + 3^n$ help what to do

Tags: number-theory

how to solve this for natural numbers $5^m = 2 + 3^n$ i did this

$5^m = 2 + 3^n \Rightarrow 5^m \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow m \equiv 1 \pmod 2$
now  if   i put it like  this
$   5^{2k+1} = 2 + 3^n $

what to do ??

now is this right another try :

$ m = n \Rightarrow 5^n - 3^n = 2 = 5 - 3 \Rightarrow (m_1,n_1)= (1,1) $

we can prove by induction :

$5^n - 3^n > 2 \quad \forall n > 1  \Rightarrow m = n = 1 $

another case :

$m > n \Rightarrow 5^m > 5^n \geq 3^n+2 \quad \forall n \geq 1 \Rightarrow 5^m - 3^n > 2 \Rightarrow \emptyset$

$m < n \Rightarrow no \ sol. $ by putting some values

Comment: Observations: (1) If $m\ge 2$ then $n\equiv 13\pmod{20}$, by considering the equation mod $25$.  (2) $\gcd(m,n)=1$ since otherwise we can factor $5^m-3^n=2$.

Comment: is my try right ??

Comment: yeah you're right

Comment: i see we can put $n = m + 1 , m + 2 , m + 3$

Comment: and see what happens is that can be right ?

Comment: $f(x) = 5^x -3^{x+1}$ ???????????!!!

Comment: $n\approx m\frac{\ln 5}{\ln 3}$ so you will need to prove $n=m+1, m+2, \ldots, m+0.7m$

Comment: i tried another way bu putting $5^{m-1} = x$ and $3^{n-1} = y $ 

$5x - 3y = 2 \Rightarrow (x_1,y_1) = (1,1) \Rightarrow \boxed{\boxed{m=n=1}}$

$ x = x_1 + bt = 1 - 3t \ and \ y = y_1 - at = 1 - 5t$

$x,y \geq 0 \Rightarrow t < \frac{1}{5}$

$ \therefore m = 1 + \log_{5}(1-3t)$

$n = 1 + \log_{5}(1-5t)$
 

$ n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 $

$ m \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $

Comment: i don't know but is it very hard ????!

Comment: @what'sup: this is not a chat room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to reformulate the problem a bit to adapt it to my usances. 
$$5^m = 2+3^n \\5^m = 5-3+3^n \\
5(5^{m-1}-1) = 3(3^{n-1}-1) $$
$$ \tag 1 {5^a-1 \over 3} = {3^b-1 \over 5} \\ 
\small \text{    we let a=m-1 and b=n-1 for shortness}$$

Now we get  concurring conditions when looking at powers of the primefactor decomposition of the lhs and the rhs.

---

*I must introduce two shorthand-notations for the following. We write*
*$\qquad 1. \qquad [a:p] = 1 $ if p is a factor in a, and $  [a:p] = 0 $ if not (this is the "Iverson-bracket")*

*$\qquad 2. \qquad \{a,p\} = m $ meaning, that* m *is the exponent, to which* p *is a primefactor in* a *.*

---

We begin to look at  *p=3* in the lhs and *q=5* in the rhs in(1) (both can occur only once in the numerators) and then at powers of the primefactor *p=2* , *p=7* and *p=13* which must be equal on both sides. It shows a systematic approach, which can also be taken for similar problems.

---

***The primefactors, which must occur differently:***

The occurence of the primefactor *3* in the lhs is determined by the formula
$$ \{5^a-1,3\} = [a:2](1 + \{a,3\}) $$ 
and because it is allowed to occur exactly once, *a* must be even and not divisible by *3* so $$a = \pm 2 \pmod 6) \tag 2$$
The occurence of the primefactor *5* in the rhs is determined by the formula
$$ \{3^b-1,5\} = [b:4](1 + \{b,5\}) $$ 
and because it is allowed to occur exactly once, *b* must be divisible by *4* and not divisible by *5* so $$b = (4,8,12,16)  \pmod {20} \tag 3$$

---

***The primefactors, which must occur equally:***

Looking at the primefactor *2* we have for the lhs:
$$ \{5^a-1,2\} = 2 + \{a,2\} \tag {3.1} $$ 
and for the rhs
$$ \{3^b-1,2\} = 1 + [b:2]+ \{b,2\}) \tag {3.2} $$

We have from the previous that *b* must be divisible by *4* so the exponent of primefactor *2* must be at least *4* by (3.2) and thus *a* must also be divisible by *4* (and must in fact have the same number of primefactors *2* as *b*).

Looking at the primefactor *7* we have for the lhs:
$$ \{5^a-1,7\} = [a:6] (1 + \{a,7\}) \tag {4.1}$$ 
and for the rhs
$$ \{3^b-1,7\} = [b:6](1 +  \{b,7\}) \tag {4.2} $$ 
From this because *a* cannot be divisible by *6* by the needed equality of powers of primefactor *7* also *b* cannot be divisible by *6*.

Looking at the primefactor *13* we have for the lhs:
$$ \{5^a-1,13\} = [a:4] (1 + \{a,13\}) \tag {5.1} $$ 
and for the rhs
$$ \{3^b-1,13\} = [b:3](1 +  \{b,13\}) \tag {5.2}$$
Now we get contradictory conditions: We know already that *a* must be divisible by *4* thus the primefactor *p=13* shall occur in the lhs of (1) by (5.1). But because *b* is even but never divisible by *6*, it is also never divisible by *3* and thus the primefactor *13* does ***not*** occur in the rhs of (1) by (5.2).

Conclusion: no further solution after the "trivial" one for *n=m=1*

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is a solution with $n>1$. Then $ 5^m \equiv 2 \pmod 9 \Rightarrow m \equiv 5 \pmod 6$.

Then $ 5^m \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \Rightarrow 3^n \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \Rightarrow n \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$

Also, $ 5^m \equiv 5 \text { or } 8 \pmod {13} \Rightarrow 3^n \equiv 3\text { or } 6 \pmod {13} \Rightarrow n \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$

This contradiction means that $n$ cannot be greater than $1$ and so $m=n=1$.

Comment: I knew there had to be something better. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. I was interested in the original proof to see when it would give anything more than the 'natural' proof - not in this case!