# Solve the diophantine equation $(n+2)^p-n^q=2$

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Let $n,p,q$ be positive integers. Solve the diophantine equation
> $$(n+2)^p-n^q=2.$$

I known this is Catalan's Conjecture, and the special case $n=3$  ([$5^m = 2 + 3^n$ help what to do](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450365/5m-2-3n-help-what-to-do)) has simple methods.

But I ask this question: have simple methods(such $n=3$)?

because it is contest math problem

Comment: $p = q = 1$ is a solution. For $(n+2)^p = n^q+2$ the solutions are for $p \lt q$

Comment: @CesarEo,Yes, It is clear,and it is said this equation is only solution

Comment: It is not exact Catalan's conjecture. It is a generalized version that is unsolved (in general, this specific equation might be completely solvable)

Comment: The case $p,q$ even can be ruled out because this would lead to $x^2+2=y^2$ , which is not solvable modulo $4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $4 \mid n$, we can quickly eliminate all $p\ge2$; when $2 \mid n$, the options are very finite and easily calculated/determined.

Now assume $n$ is odd. Expanding the first term yields $2^p$ plus a whole bunch of terms with a factor of $n$. Therefore, we can reduce the equation modulo $n$ to find $$2^p \equiv 2\!\!\!\!\pmod{n},$$ and since $n$ is odd, this implies $$2^{p-1} \equiv 1\!\!\!\!\pmod{n}.$$ This equation is well represented in the literature, and there are elementary and relatively simple methods available to attack/solve it.